# How do I create a window in mac using c++ and opengl?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, opengl

I am new to mac development. I have currently started on a 3d program using windows (using direct3d) and i am looking to expand to mac using opengl. I currently have code on how to initualize the window and draw in it using opengl and windows. I am looking for the most seemless way to replace the windows part of this application with a mac interface.

```
bool SystemClass::InitializeWindows(OpenGLClass* OpenGL, int& screenWidth, int&screenHeight){
WNDCLASSEX wc;
DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
int posX, posY;

ApplicationHandle = this;
m_hinstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

m_applicationName = L"Engine";

wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.hInstance     = m_hinstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
wc.hIconSm       = wc.hIcon;
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = m_applicationName;
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    //etc 
    //set full screen mode
    //set window to front
    //hide mouse
```

When i was researching this i saw many people using objective-c or coco, do i have to use objective-c or coco to get the result i want? and if so can i still use c++ or objective-c++ with the coco library?

Lastly what is the easiest equivalent to the messagebox() in mac? I used NSGetCriticalAlertPanel() but i could not seem to get it to work (mostly because i could not find what the corresponding library i had to include).

PS: I am using xcode compiler, if there is a better one out there or one you prefer more please suggest it (im not a big fan of xcode).

Comment: There is no way to create a window with openGL it is an api for rendering only.  Window creation will be some platform specific code, eventually you will call an A(apple)GL function to create an openGL rendering context.

Comment: It's called Cocoa not coco. And yes, you'll have to use Objective-C(/++), because MacOS X is fundamentally rooted on its message based OOP system. And Cocoa is to MacOS X what the Win32 API is to windows.

Comment: For beginners (and for ports like these), I would not recommend you using Cocoa as there's quite the learning curve.  Instead, use libraries such as SDL.

Comment: thanx for all the comment, does any one have any good tutorial or reference page? (for said topic)

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [this SDL - openGL tutorial](http://www.meandmark.com/sdlopenglpart1.html) it is up to date. You will need also to install [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) what you probably have. There are detailed instroctions in the tutorial on how to install inlcude SDL into your project. After everthing is initialized and ready to use you can find lots of [general sdl tutorials here](http://www.sdltutorials.com/), you could focus on this [sdltutorial on openGL](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics).

Maybe [this SDL FAQ](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/FAQMacOSX) can be helpful too.